# How to make Google Maps remember your searches?

Tags: google-maps

I have typed my own address when looking for directions into Google Maps about 7,000 times*.

In the past, until sometime in the last year, it *used* to remember places that I searched for and I only had to type the first couple numbers and then select from the dropdown.

Why did they take this behavior away in favor of the "search the whole world" behavior?

What can I do to make Google Maps learn my address without having to constantly jump thru hoops to select it?

I hate what they are doing/have done to what was such an awesome product. :-(

*rough, but probably accurate, estimate

Answer (score 1):

Google gives the ability for you to store the location of favorite addresses such as your home, work, school, etc.

To save a location, first log into your Google account and then search Google Maps for the location you want to save.  Next, click on the push-pin associated with the location to display the context bubble for that spot.

At the bottom of the context bubble is an option to Save to map.  Click it, enter a name for the location and hit save.

After saving the location, you will notice on the left (right underneath the Google Maps logo) a link that says "My Places".  Click on the My Places link to display the list of saved locations, which should include the location you just added.

See the image below for reference.

[image]

Comment: I would rather not have to save it to a list, and then go hunt it down.  I just want to type an address, and, if I have typed it *many times before* I want it autocompleted.  It used to do this.  No way to re-enable?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option on the left hand side of the page that reads: **Set default location**

I think in the redesign of the look of Google's pages some information was lost. Google also lost my saved autocomplete for maps information. Though it might be a browser issue also.

Comment: No, it's had this problem for several months.